# Parsing json with mysql

Tags: mysql, json, parsing

How to parse Json in MySQL level?
I've version MySQL version 5.6.26 in XAMPP

```
MySQL --version
MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.26, for Win32 (x86)
```

I created a table.

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Inserted some rows

```
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(1,'{"from":"chris","title":"Awesome Article","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(2,'{"from":"loren","title":"Another Article","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');
INSERT INTO message (id,data) VALUES(3,'{"from":"jason","title":"How to run a query","body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."}');
```

and I try to get Json values:

```
SELECT Json_get(data,'title') FROM message WHERE id=2;
```

And I get error:

> SELECT json_get(data,'title') FROM message WHERE id=2;
>       ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION mydatabasename.json_get does not exist

Has anybody ideas?

Comment: I am not very experienced with it, but I think if your data is in Json, you should use a NoSQL database, or if you use an SQL database, you better do the parsing in the business logic. It looks like you try to make your SQL database behave like a NoSQL one...

Comment: In an SQL database, your scheme would be static and your `message` table would contain all the fields that are in the Json data

Answer (score 2):

You can parse json data using `common_schema`, try following code it may help you :-

```
SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(data,'title') FROM message WHERE id=2;
```

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work:  SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(data,'title') FROM message WHERE id=2;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION common_schema.extract_json_value does not exist

Comment: You have to install [common_schema](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/common_schema-2-2-better-queryscript-isolation-tokudb-table_rotate-split-params) first.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mysql to 5.7 and you can use [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) which is predefined by MySQL to handle your json data.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of [json_function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) you can do this.

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data,'$.title') FROM message WHERE id=1`