# Is there any way to use values from a JSON object in a SQL Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I want to write a query to select all the records where the values in the properties of a JSON object match a given string. For example, let's say I have a table with a column for address, which is a JSON object. The address for the first record looks like this:

```
{
 "addressLine": "123 fake road"
 "city": "Buffalo"
 "state": "New York"
}
```

And the address for the second record looks like this:

```
{
 "addressLine": "123 fake road"
 "city": "New Haven"
 "state": "Connecticut"
}
```

Would it be possible to write a query given the word 'New’ that would return both records since the values of the JSON contains that string? Thanks!

Comment: Add a tag for the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: after adding mysql tag, Check my answer update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve JSON data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON_EXTRACT function:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE json_extract(JsonColumn, '$.city') like 'New%'
```

**Additional information**

- [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)
- [Parsing json with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510546/parsing-json-with-mysql?rq=1)
- [How to retrieve JSON data from mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql)
- [How can write queries in MySQL that can parse JSON data in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137915/how-can-write-queries-in-mysql-that-can-parse-json-data-in-a-column)

Comment: How does that answer the question? I don't see anything in the code that searches something. And I miss a clear attribution to the originator of the code.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `json_extract(JsonColumn, '$.city') like 'New%'`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i provided the method that the OP can benefit from and showed an example of how to read columns from JSON. how it is not related??

Comment: If that answers the question, then it should be closed as duplicate of where you have copied the code from.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i copied the code from GitHub and i provided the link, in addition i provided all links that can be similar to this question. Also, you have the right to mark it as duplicate

Comment: But it's not clear in the answer, that it's not your work. And again - Why copy an answer instead of voting to close the question as duplicate?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel ohhh , i didn't mentioned that the same code from github is found on the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701579/how-to-retrieve-json-data-from-mysql) i have followed the link without reading the code provided below. Now, you are right. i will update my answer, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel also i removed the SQL Server pert. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now it's actually **your** answer and more related to the question. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) for the next time.